# Can't access static property in generic type but can in interface

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, asp.net-core-7.0

When I inject options, I use the following configuration approach.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
  {
    IConfiguration config = host.Configuration;
    ...
    services.Configure<SomeConfig>(
      config.GetSection(new SomeConfig().SectionKey));
  }).Build();
```

I have, of course, the interface and implementing class like so.

```
public interface IConfig
{
  public string SectionKey { get; }
}

public class SomeConfig : IConfig
{
  public string SectionKey => "SomeConfig";
  ...
}
```

Now, it's a minor issue but it still bugs me that the `SectionKey` property isn't static. It **will** after all be exactly the same in each instance of the class. Hence, I've tried to appoach it as follows.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
  {
    IConfiguration config = host.Configuration;
    ...
    services.Configure<SomeConfig>(
      config.GetSection(SomeConfig.SectionKey));
  }).Build();

public interface IConfig
{
  public static string SectionKey { get; }
}

public class SomeConfig : IConfig
{
  public static string SectionKey => "SomeConfig";
  ...
}
```

The natural step is now to create an extension method so I'll be able to execute my configurations' injection like this.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
  {
    IConfiguration config = host.Configuration;
    ...
    services.Config<SomeConfig>(config);
  }).Build();
```

Neat, right? However, I get stuck in the creation of the extention method because it works only if I create an instance of `T` and get the `SectionKey` value that's non-static.

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection Config<T>(
    this IServiceCollection self, IConfiguration config)
    where T : class, IConfig, new()
  {
    string key = new T().SectionKey;
    IServiceCollection output = self.Configure<T>(
      config.GetSection(key));

    return output;
  }
}
```

What I'd see as more optimal, is to be able to pull out the value of the `SectionKey` as an instance variable or, maybe even better, as a constant field! But it seems that the setup below fails.

```
public interface IConfig
{
  public string SectionKey { get; }
  public static string SectionKeyStatic { get; } = default!;
  public const string SectionKeyConst = default!;
}

public class SomeConfig : IConfig
{
  public string SectionKey => "SomeConfig";
  public static string SectionKeyStatic => "SomeConfig";
  public const string SectionKeyConst = "SomeConfig";
}
```

When I try to access the value of the key, the first two line work well, while the last two won't.

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection Config<T>(
    this IServiceCollection self, IConfiguration config)
    where T : class, IConfig, new()
  {
    string thisWorks = IConfig.SectionKeyStatic;
    string thisToo = IConfig.SectionKeyConst;
    string thisFails = T.SectionKeyStatic;
    string thisAlso = T.SectionKeyConst;
    ...
  }
}
```

I can't explain why nor how to resolve it. So for the time being I'm using the original strategy and live on bugged to the bones.

Comment: Did you try to make that an [`abstract static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/static-abstract-interface-methods) interface member?

Comment: @Fildor Dude... Seriously...? I've been coding .NET since 2003, version 0.9. I have **not** used `abstract` on a property even one single time, for duck's quacks' sake. I only used `abstract` in a few, rare occasions (since interface and implementing class suffice more than well). So: **no**, I certainly have not tried that. Well... I have... now. It's pretty obvious now, after you pointed that out... Please post it as a reply to be accepted as the answer. Please, pretty please, with cherry on top, make it a bit longer and complex so I don't feel like an ass...   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this document that describes the breaking change in .NET 6 (generally available in 7+) which allows for having `abstract static` interface members for reasons that sound very much like your use case.

Quote:

> This change was introduced because there was no way to abstract over static members and write generalized code that applies across types that define those static members.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/static-abstract-interface-methods

And related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members#static-abstract-interface-methods

Comment: Note that for .NET 6 it is a preview feature (requires additional setup), generally available it became in .NET 7.

Comment: @GuruStron Are you saying that `abstract` is a new feature from version 7 (for properties, that is)? How was that handled before that? I discovered yesterday that it was possible thanks to Fildor because I never had the need before. Was my timing so great? I'm suspicious...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm saying that static abstract members are new feature released with .NET 7. Yes, it was. Though .NET 7 was released several months ago)